# Non-Convex Polyhedron With 4 or 5 Faces

Tags: geometry, 3d, convex-geometry

Finding convex polyhedron with 4 or 5 faces seems easy but I am trying to find non convex polyhedron with 4 or 5 faces.

Is there any non-convex polyhedron with 4 or 5 faces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does this dart pyramid work for you?

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know a non convex polyhedron with 4 faces? If know can you proof this please?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^3$ all 4 faced polygons are tetrahedra and convex

Comment: Thanks Vasily Mitch. How can I prove it?

Comment: 4 faces set 4 planes. What kind of regions you can get out of 4 planes?